# Where can I find Solidity's units and globally-available variables in Python's web3 package?

Tags: solidity, python, web3.py

Units and globally-available variables in Solidity are described [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html).

Where can I find the corresponding entities inside Python's `web3` package?

Specifically, I am interested in Solidity's time units (`seconds`, `minutes`, `hours`, etc).

I searched inside the [Web3.py guide](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but I have not been able to find them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `web.py` has any convenience functions for them, but Python has [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

```
>>> timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()
86400.0
```